# How to execute script after system reboot by using kickstart

Tags: rhel, reboot, rhel6

I'm using PXE to install ISO. There are two scripts for environment configuration, I want to added them in kickstart file, so the environment will be setup completely and automatically after the system installed.

However, my situation is:

1. Script 1 must reboot (has been added in script1.sh)
2. Script 2 depends on script 1

Here part of kickstart file:

```
...
...
%post

wget http://xxx/script1.sh
wget http://xxx/script2.sh

sh -x script1.sh | tee script1.log
sh -x script2.sh | tee script2.log

%end
```

So, is there anyway that script 2 can be executed after system reboot by using kickstart file? Or the other way, just executed the script 2 once after reboot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I have done this is to make a startup script that calls secondary script(s), which in your case are `script1.sh` and `script2.sh`.

Here is one reference about [configuring RHEL 6 Runlevels and Services](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_RHEL_6_Runlevels_and_Services).  Alternatively, if have access to an existing RHEL/CentOS system you could browse `/etc/init.d/` and copy one of the simpler startup scripts there as the basis for your own.

To put this all together, you'll need to:

*In your kickstart file*

1. Add an additional `wget` call to download the startup script you created.
2. You'll need to copy/move the startup script to `/etc/init.d` .  Keep in mind that `%post` is [run in a chroot environment](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-postinstallconfig.html).
3. Enable the startup script on boot with `chkconfig`.

*In your startup script*

4. Upon successful completion of `script2.sh`, disable the startup script with another `chkconfig *service_name* off` so it isn't run on future reboots.

Comment: Great! Actually this is exactly what I did. I added the `script2.sh` in `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`. And add the self-delete to make sure it will be deleted from `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` after it's executed.

Comment: Great!  Glad it worked for you.  I have found this "firstboot" approach to be an easier way to manage the post installation configuration than packing the commands in `%post`.